# Serving Firebase via CDNs instead of npm modules in an Angular App

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

I am building an angular app which uses firebase.
I was using firebase by by doing an `npm install firebase`. But this is adding into my bundle size which i don't want.

So i tried serving the firebase files via CDNs and pasted the links right into `index.html` like:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>
<script src="./init-firebase.js"></script>
```

and to initialize firebase, i made an init-firebase.js file which has contents like:

```
let firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  databaseURL: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: ""
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Doing this much should initialize a firebase project for me.

Now, that problem is in accessing the firebase app from inside of angular. Because of difference of the module system, i am unable to access the firebase app from inside of angular

I tried writing the following code in `app.module.ts` for debugging, but got no help.

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

try {
  console.log(firebase.app.length);
  console.log(firebase.apps[0]);
  firebase.app();
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}

console.log(firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig));
console.log(firebase.app.length);
```

The output is:

```
1 <- output 1
undefined <- output 2
FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).
    at Object.app (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:113625:33)
    at Module../src/app/app.module.ts (http://localhost:4200/main.js:202:54)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:4200/runtime.js:85:30)
    at Module../src/main.ts (http://localhost:4200/main.js:1550:73)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:4200/runtime.js:85:30)
    at Object.0 (http://localhost:4200/main.js:1573:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:4200/runtime.js:85:30)
    at checkDeferredModules (http://localhost:4200/runtime.js:46:23)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (http://localhost:4200/runtime.js:33:19)
    at http://localhost:4200/main.js:1:57 <- output 3
FirebaseAppImpl {firebase_: {…}, isDeleted_: false, name_: "[DEFAULT]", automaticDataCollectionEnabled_: false, options_: {…}, …} <- output 4
1 <- output 5
```

For further help, If I'm doing `console.log(firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig));`  from inside of `firebase-init.js`, I get a slight different output format than if i do it from `app.module.ts`, indicating potential difference due to module systems.

Please help me on the issue.

And if you need a small repo which can replicate the issue, please let me know.
Thank you.

**UPDATE**: after writing the following line: `declare var firebase: any;` in the files I'm using firebase, I'm able to use it. But only functionality is available, not the typings.

Anyone knows how to get the typings as well? Thank you.

Comment: Angular or AngularJS?

Comment: Angular @YaakovHatam

Comment: Are you using the official Firebase module for angular?

Comment: Yes, the gstatic links are real, and I'm able to use firebase just fine, i just want to have the typings now.

Comment: I am not sure it applies to angular projects but you would look into webpack code spliting so you can keep your npm dependency of firebase while generating a separate bundle file or chunk for third party libs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Types are there only in the firebase package unless you include it, there won't be types. You have to manually write the types you want or use any to make this work. There is no other alternative other than including the package.